# Get the mean across multiple Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, r, numpy, pandas

I'm generating a number of dataframes with the same shape, and I want to compare them to one another. I want to be able to get the mean and median across the dataframes.

```
         Source.0  Source.1  Source.2  Source.3
cluster                                        
0        0.001182  0.184535  0.814230  0.000054
1        0.000001  0.160490  0.839508  0.000001
2        0.000001  0.173829  0.826114  0.000055
3        0.000432  0.180065  0.819502  0.000001
4        0.000152  0.157041  0.842694  0.000113
5        0.000183  0.174142  0.825674  0.000001
6        0.000001  0.151556  0.848405  0.000038
7        0.000771  0.177583  0.821645  0.000001
8        0.000001  0.202059  0.797939  0.000001
9        0.000025  0.189537  0.810410  0.000028
10       0.006142  0.003041  0.493912  0.496905
11       0.003739  0.002367  0.514216  0.479678
12       0.002334  0.001517  0.529041  0.467108
13       0.003458  0.000001  0.532265  0.464276
14       0.000405  0.005655  0.527576  0.466364
15       0.002557  0.003233  0.507954  0.486256
16       0.004161  0.000001  0.491271  0.504568
17       0.001364  0.001330  0.528311  0.468996
18       0.002886  0.000001  0.506392  0.490721
19       0.001823  0.002498  0.509620  0.486059

         Source.0  Source.1  Source.2  Source.3
cluster                                        
0        0.000001  0.197108  0.802495  0.000396
1        0.000001  0.157860  0.842076  0.000063
2        0.094956  0.203057  0.701662  0.000325
3        0.000001  0.181948  0.817841  0.000210
4        0.000003  0.169680  0.830316  0.000001
5        0.000362  0.177194  0.822443  0.000001
6        0.000001  0.146807  0.852924  0.000268
7        0.001087  0.178994  0.819564  0.000354
8        0.000001  0.202182  0.797333  0.000485
9        0.000348  0.181399  0.818252  0.000001
10       0.003050  0.000247  0.506777  0.489926
11       0.004420  0.000001  0.513927  0.481652
12       0.006488  0.001396  0.527197  0.464919
13       0.001510  0.000001  0.525987  0.472502
14       0.000001  0.000001  0.520737  0.479261
15       0.000001  0.001765  0.515658  0.482575
16       0.000001  0.000001  0.492550  0.507448
17       0.002855  0.000199  0.526535  0.470411
18       0.000001  0.001952  0.498303  0.499744
19       0.001232  0.000001  0.506612  0.492155
```

Then I want to get the mean of these two dataframes.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Just to clarify I want to get the mean for each particular cell when the indexes and columns of all the dataframes are exactly the same.

So in the example I gave, the average for `[0,Source.0]` would be (0.001182 + 0.000001) / 2 = 0.0005915.

Comment: What mean exactly: one single value per variable, or one value per variable-cluster?

Comment: For the record, display your data as `df.reset_index()` if you want us to use your data for test cases.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Assuming the two dataframes have the same columns, you could just concatenate them and compute your summary stats on the concatenated frames:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# some random data frames
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=np.random.randn(100), y=np.random.randint(0, 5, 100)))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=np.random.randn(100), y=np.random.randint(0, 5, 100)))

# concatenate them
df_concat = pd.concat((df1, df2))

print df_concat.mean()
# x   -0.163044
# y    2.120000
# dtype: float64

print df_concat.median()
# x   -0.192037
# y    2.000000
# dtype: float64
```

### Update

If you want to compute stats across each set of rows with the same index in the two datasets, you can use `.groupby()` to group the data by row index, then apply the mean, median etc.:

```
by_row_index = df_concat.groupby(df_concat.index)
df_means = by_row_index.mean()

print df_means.head()
#           x    y
# 0 -0.850794  1.5
# 1  0.159038  1.5
# 2  0.083278  1.0
# 3 -0.540336  0.5
# 4  0.390954  3.5
```

This method will work even when your dataframes have unequal numbers of rows - if a particular row index is missing in one of the two dataframes, the mean/median will be computed on the single existing row.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Bot the columns and the indexes are the same but I want to get the average accross only one position in the DF if that makes sense, so in the example i gave the average for [0,Source.0] would be (0.001182 + 0.000001) / 2

Comment: You should have responded this to my question in the comments to the original question also ;)

Comment: @TimRich `.groupby()` is probably the simplest way to do this - see @FooBar's answer and my update

Answer (score 21):

I go similar as @ali_m, but since you want one mean per row-column combination, I conclude differently:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=np.random.randn(100), y=np.random.randint(0, 5, 100)))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=np.random.randn(100), y=np.random.randint(0, 5, 100)))
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
foo = df.groupby(level=1).mean()
foo.head()

          x    y
0  0.841282  2.5
1  0.716749  1.0
2 -0.551903  2.5
3  1.240736  1.5
4  1.227109  2.0
```

Comment: much faster than my general function, you can also use apply on this for more general functions

Comment: great solution!   I just had to use Level=1 to not Group on the dataframe names. `foo = df.groupby(level=1).mean()`

Comment: This solute gives me `ValueError: level > 0 or level < -1 only valid with MultiIndex` with Pandas 1.3.2.

Comment: Maybe my solution will help, @Mead

Answer (score 18):

As per Niklas' comment, the solution to the question is `panel.mean(axis=0)`.

As a more complete example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dfs = {}
nrows = 4
ncols = 3
for i in range(4):
    dfs[i] = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(i, nrows*ncols+i).reshape(nrows, ncols),
                          columns=list('abc'))
    print('DF{i}:\n{df}\n'.format(i=i, df=dfs[i]))

panel = pd.Panel(dfs)
print('Mean of stacked DFs:\n{df}'.format(df=panel.mean(axis=0)))
```

Will give the following output:

```
DF0:
   a   b   c
0  0   1   2
1  3   4   5
2  6   7   8
3  9  10  11

DF1:
    a   b   c
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   9
3  10  11  12

DF2:
    a   b   c
0   2   3   4
1   5   6   7
2   8   9  10
3  11  12  13

DF3:
    a   b   c
0   3   4   5
1   6   7   8
2   9  10  11
3  12  13  14

Mean of stacked DFs:
      a     b     c
0   1.5   2.5   3.5
1   4.5   5.5   6.5
2   7.5   8.5   9.5
3  10.5  11.5  12.5
```

Comment: Ooh I didn't know about panel. Very useful for blending/stacking dataframes.

Comment: Mind that the class Panel is now deprecated and will be removed in future versions of Pandas.

Comment: Very useful, thank you very much for sharing your knowledge

Answer (score 9):

Here is a solution first unstack both dataframes so they are series with multiindexes(cluster, colnames)... then you can use Series addition and division, which automattically do the operation on the indexes, finally unstack them... here it is in code...

```
averages = (df1.stack()+df2.stack())/2
averages = averages.unstack()
```

And your done...

Or for more general purposes...

```
dfs = [df1,df2]
averages = pd.concat([each.stack() for each in dfs],axis=1)\
             .apply(lambda x:x.mean(),axis=1)\
             .unstack()
```

Comment: That'll work fine for the mean, but it's harder to generalize to other summary stats such as the median, which the OP was also asking for.

Comment: Didn't keep that in mind when I made the answer but I do think that this solution would absolutely be able to do that you can combine each of the series I made into a dataframe and run the median solution on the frame rowwise yeilding you the seiries which you can unstack

Answer (score 6):

You can simply assign a label to each frame, call it `group` and then `concat` and `groupby` to do what you want:

```
In [57]: df = DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('abcd'))

In [58]: df2 = df.copy()

In [59]: dfs = [df, df2]

In [60]: df
Out[60]:
        a       b       c       d
0  0.1959  0.1260  0.1464  0.1631
1  0.9344 -1.8154  1.4529 -0.6334
2  0.0390  0.4810  1.1779 -1.1799
3  0.3542  0.3819 -2.0895  0.8877
4 -2.2898 -1.0585  0.8083 -0.2126
5  0.3727 -0.6867 -1.3440 -1.4849
6 -1.1785  0.0885  1.0945 -1.6271
7 -1.7169  0.3760 -1.4078  0.8994
8  0.0508  0.4891  0.0274 -0.6369
9 -0.7019  1.0425 -0.5476 -0.5143

In [61]: for i, d in enumerate(dfs):
   ....:     d['group'] = i
   ....:

In [62]: dfs[0]
Out[62]:
        a       b       c       d  group
0  0.1959  0.1260  0.1464  0.1631      0
1  0.9344 -1.8154  1.4529 -0.6334      0
2  0.0390  0.4810  1.1779 -1.1799      0
3  0.3542  0.3819 -2.0895  0.8877      0
4 -2.2898 -1.0585  0.8083 -0.2126      0
5  0.3727 -0.6867 -1.3440 -1.4849      0
6 -1.1785  0.0885  1.0945 -1.6271      0
7 -1.7169  0.3760 -1.4078  0.8994      0
8  0.0508  0.4891  0.0274 -0.6369      0
9 -0.7019  1.0425 -0.5476 -0.5143      0

In [63]: final = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)

In [64]: final
Out[64]:
         a       b       c       d  group
0   0.1959  0.1260  0.1464  0.1631      0
1   0.9344 -1.8154  1.4529 -0.6334      0
2   0.0390  0.4810  1.1779 -1.1799      0
3   0.3542  0.3819 -2.0895  0.8877      0
4  -2.2898 -1.0585  0.8083 -0.2126      0
5   0.3727 -0.6867 -1.3440 -1.4849      0
6  -1.1785  0.0885  1.0945 -1.6271      0
..     ...     ...     ...     ...    ...
13  0.3542  0.3819 -2.0895  0.8877      1
14 -2.2898 -1.0585  0.8083 -0.2126      1
15  0.3727 -0.6867 -1.3440 -1.4849      1
16 -1.1785  0.0885  1.0945 -1.6271      1
17 -1.7169  0.3760 -1.4078  0.8994      1
18  0.0508  0.4891  0.0274 -0.6369      1
19 -0.7019  1.0425 -0.5476 -0.5143      1

[20 rows x 5 columns]

In [65]: final.groupby('group').mean()
Out[65]:
           a       b       c       d
group
0     -0.394 -0.0576 -0.0682 -0.4339
1     -0.394 -0.0576 -0.0682 -0.4339
```

Here, each `group` is the same, but that's only because `df == df2`.

Alternatively, you can throw the frames into a `Panel`:

```
In [69]: df = DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('abcd'))

In [70]: df2 = DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('abcd'))

In [71]: panel = pd.Panel({0: df, 1: df2})

In [72]: panel
Out[72]:
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 2 (items) x 10 (major_axis) x 4 (minor_axis)
Items axis: 0 to 1
Major_axis axis: 0 to 9
Minor_axis axis: a to d

In [73]: panel.mean()
Out[73]:
        0       1
a  0.3839  0.2956
b  0.1855 -0.3164
c -0.1167 -0.0627
d -0.2338 -0.0450
```

Comment: A bit late but it should be "panel.mean(**axis=0**)" based on what the question was asking. I just came across this post and really like the Panel idea! Thanks for that!

Answer (score 3):

With Pandas version 1.3.4 this works for me:

```
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=np.random.randn(100), y=np.random.randint(0, 5, 100), z=np.random.randint(-3, 2, 100)))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=np.random.randn(100), y=np.random.randint(0, 2, 100), z=np.random.randint(-1, 2, 100)))
pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby(level=0).mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

For computing the mean of a list of pandas DataFrames, I find it simplest to use:
`mean_df = sum(df_list)/len(df_list)`

For computing median or other stats using pandas, you need to use multiindex grouping in which can be a clunky solution.  I prefer to use numpy, which can accept DataFrames as inputs and has a natural mechanism for stacking and aggregating along a new axis that many will be familiar with:
`medians = np.median(np.stack(df_list), axis=0)`

np.stack() creates a new axis 0
np.median(axis=0) aggregates along the new axis