# How can I average values from two dataframes (same index) into one df, with conditions on missing values NaN?

Tags: python, pandas

I work with two dataframes (one is derived of Rainfall data from 1981 till now, the other one of Vegetation Index data from 2002 till now).

pR:

```
MonthDekad            01d1        01d2       01d3       02d1       02d2  \
AdminCode Year                                                            
2688      1981    2.702703    2.702703   2.702703   2.702703   2.702703   
          1982   16.216216   21.621622  18.918919  32.432432  54.054054   
          ...........   
          2016   0.166331     0.318759   0.431364   0.492916   0.632023   
          2017  -0.492916    -0.431364        NaN        NaN        NaN
```

and pV:

```
MonthDekad          01d1      01d2      01d3      02d1      02d2  \
AdminCode Year                                                               
2688      2002       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN        
          2003  0.477121  0.477121  0.477121  0.477121  0.477121       
          ............ 
          2016       NaN  0.636822  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000 
          2017 -0.636822 -0.636822       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

Both are indexed the same way (multi-indexed, level0 = admincode for the localisation, level1 for the year) and columns are the dekads of the year.

I need to combine them into one dataframe, by

- averaging the 2 values corresponding to the same index position, only if the values are both numbers,
- otherwise (if one of the two is missing / NaN), the final value should be the one not missing (e.g.: for 1981 till 2002, only rainfall values).
- Of course if both are NaN, it'll be NaN too.

I am blocked with the second conditional. So far, I have only thought of

```
pRV = pR.add(pV, fill_value=0)
```

that I then divide by 2 but it's a problem when only one value is added because it'll divide it too... Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25058102/3419537

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First concat 2 DFs and then group by all indexes. Finally take the mean for each key.

```
pd.concat([pR,pV]).groupby(level=[0,1]).mean()
```

Comment: No worries. Please upvote and accept one of the answers if you find it helpful.