# Compute the mean and the mode across a list of DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a list of DataFrames as it can be seen below:

```
[              Distance_Error
 Customer_id
      A             2
      B             3
      C             6
               Distance_Error
 Customer_id
      A             2
      B             3
      C             7
               Distance_Error
 Customer_id
      A             1
      B             3
      C             6]
```

I need to get the mean and the mode across these Dataframes so that, for example for the mean, I get a result like:

```
  Customer_id  Distance_Error
      A            1.6666
      B            3
      C            6.3333
```

How could I do something like this? I have tried to concatenate all of the frames (as suggested in here: [Get the mean across multiple Pandas DataFrames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25057835/get-the-mean-across-multiple-pandas-dataframes)) but I get some weird results:

```
              0             
   0   [Distance_Error]
```

Comment: If your list is named: `dfs`; `pd.concat(dfs).groupby('Customer_id').mean().reset_index()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can do:

```
df_lst = [df1,df2, df3]

pd.concat(df_lst, axis=1).mean(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
Customer_id
A    1.666667
B    3.000000
C    6.333333
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

Do something fun

```
l = [df1, df2, df3]
df = sum(l)/len(l)
```