# Average over dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a direct way to take the average over multiple dataframes (multiple runs of a simulation for example)? 
One way that I am using, with 3 dataframmes (df1, df2, df3), but is not the most efficient when having a large number of dataframes is:

```py
(df1+df2+df3)/3
```

Is there a way to just tell Python to do something more direct like `mean(df1,df2,df3)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the mean across multiple Pandas DataFrames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25057835/get-the-mean-across-multiple-pandas-dataframes)

Comment: Could you make this question a bit more clear, I am not finding it clear if you want to sum all then numeric values in 3 dataframes and average them? Do you have any data and output you could share with us please?

Comment: Assuming each dataframe is uniquely indexed, and all have the same index: `pd.concat((df1, df2, df3)).mean(level=0)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid `concat` it is possible to convert all data to numpy arrays and use `mean` by `axis=0`, last convert output to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
         'A':[4,5,4],
         'B':[7,8,90],
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
         'A':[4,50,4],
         'B':[7,8,9],
})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({
         'A':[40,5,4],
         'B':[7,8,9],
})

print ((df1+df2+df3)/3)
      A     B
0  16.0   7.0
1  20.0   8.0
2   4.0  36.0

dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([x.to_numpy() for x in dfs]).mean(axis=0), 
                  index=df1.index, 
                  columns=df1.columns)
print (df)
      A     B
0  16.0   7.0
1  20.0   8.0
2   4.0  36.0
```

For oldier pandas version change [`DataFrame.to_numpy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) to [`DataFrame.values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([x.values for x in dfs]).mean(axis=0), 
                  index=df1.index, 
                  columns=df1.columns)
```

Comment: thanks! This answers my question, I'm just surprised that there isn't a built in function that does this directly as in Mathematica for example.

Comment: @Karim - I think not yet, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously all data cells contain numeric data, if you calculate the mean like this.
The only enhancement I could think of is to use numpy arrays.

```
import numpy as np

def df_mean(*dfs):
    return np.array([np.array(df) for df in dfs]).mean(axis=0)

df_mean(df1, df2, df3) # you can put as many dfs as arguments as you want.
```

Ah @jezrael just posted the same idea.